# KonvaJs: Subgroup not rendering in correct position in relation to parent group

Tags: konvajs

I am trying to get an information card (consisting of a Konva.Rect and Konva.Text) to appear below an image while hovering over it. I've tried combining the info card into a separate child group and added it to a parent group that consists of the image and the image label. The issue is that when hovering over the image the rectangle appears far off to the right rather than in the correct x,y position. How can I set the child group's coordinates such that if the image moves across the screen the info card will always appear below it?

I've tried setting the rectangle's `x` attribute as `group.x()` (where group is the parent group's x coordinate). I've also tried setting it as `image.x()` yet the rectangle still appears far off to the right of the parent image.

```
let group = new Konva.Group({
      x: 100,
      y: 20,
      id: attr.status,
      visible: ng.checkboxValues[status] ? true : false,
    });
    let image = new Konva.Image({
      x: group.x(),
      y: group.y(),
      image: DOMImage,
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      listening: true,
      visible: true,
    });
    let robotAlias = new Konva.Text({
      x: image.x() - 20,
      y: image.y() + 10,
      text: attr.alias,
      fontSize: 13,
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      fill: ng.colorMap[attr.status],
      visible: true,
    });
    let complexText = new Konva.Text({
      x: image.x(),
      y: image.y(),
      text: `${attr.alias}-${attr.status}`,
      fontSize: 15,
      padding: 10,
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      align: 'center',
      fill: this.colorMap[attr.status],
      height: 60,
      width: 160,
      visible: true,
    });

    let rect = new Konva.Rect({
      x: image.x(),
      y: image.y(),
      stroke: '#fff',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      fill: '#fff',
      height: 60,
      width: 160,
      shadowColor: 'black',
      shadowBlur: 5,
      shadowOffset: [10, 10],
      shadowOpacity: 0.2,
      visible: true,
    });

    let descriptionCardGroup = new Konva.Group({
      x: image.x(),
      y: image.y(),
      visible: false,
      name: `${attr.id}`,
    })

    group.add(image);
    group.add(robotAlias);
    descriptionCardGroup.add(rect);
    descriptionCardGroup.add(complexText);
    group.add(descriptionCardGroup);
```

Here's a screenshot of the current behavior: https://ibb.co/QMYjxrw

Comment: You are adding rect and text into the `descriptionCardGroup` with a defined position. That will double the position of the nodes. E.g. if rect has `x = image.x()` and it is places into group with `x = image.x()`, the absolute position will be `image.x() * 2`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response .

If I were to try to move the group and its contents using `group.position`, would the children move accordingly or will I have to access each child and change their position as well? 

Also, any advice on how I should go about placing `descriptionCardGroup` and its children? I've tried giving descCardGroup x = 0 (so it's on the same x as the parent group) and y = 10.

Comment: If you change the `position` of a group, the absolute position of all children will be changed to. (but not `position` property of children).
`position` is always relative to the parent element.